# How to use a variable inside a URL in flutter

Tags: flutter, url

Why this is working?

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http..../?page=2"),
```

And this is not working?

```
int p = 2;
String page = p.toString();
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http..../?page="+p),
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http..../?page=$p"),
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose Uri.https has a `Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,` property.

You can use it this way:

```
  final p = 2;
  final parameters = <String, String>{
     'page': p.toString(),
    };
  
  
  final uri = Uri.http(
    'http....com',
    '/',
    parameters,
  );
  final response = await httpClient.get(uri);
```